# Proving closed interval [0,1] has same cardinality as Real Numbers

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, real-numbers, cardinals

I want to prove that the closed interval [0, 1] has same cardinality as Real Numbers. I was able to figure out (0, 1), but need help with proving the closed part. What I have so far is:

the function $y = tan x$ gives us a bijection between $(−π/2, π/2)$
and $R$, and that the function $y = (2x − 1)π/2$
gives a bijection between $(0, 1)$
and $(−π/2, π/2)$. Therefore $y = tan
(2x − 1)π/2$ gives a bijection between
(0, 1) and $R$.

How do I finish this off for the closed aspect?

Comment: Why not create a bijective mapping between $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$?

Comment: There is an injection of $[0,1]$ into $\mathbb{R}$, so you know that the cardinality of $[0,1]$ is $\leq$ the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$.  You have already proved the opposite inequality, so you are done.